# FFMpeg : Creating a video clip of approx. 10 seconds when video duration is unknown without audio-

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, ffmpeg

I am working on a project where I am looking to extract a video clip from an input video. I have found many links(Eg : [link](https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg)) which do this task, but in all this I have to specify video duration.

Unfortunately I don't have that information as I am giving a file-path. What I am looking for is a 10 seconds clip from the video which is saved at specific location without the audio part.

My intention is to show that 10 seconds video as a preview of the actual video in the front end, and I don't want to start sound in that.

Answer (score 12):

You are most likely after:

```
ffmpeg -i "A_File.mp4" -ss 00:00:0.0 -t 10 -an "B_File.mp4"
```

To do it a bit faster you can also try adding `-threads $(nproc)` eg:

```
ffmpeg -threads $(nproc) -i "A_File.mp4" -ss 00:00:0.0 -t 10 -an "B_File.mp4"
```

There is already a substantial number of articles and documentation on achieving these results including:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

http://www.labnol.org/internet/useful-ffmpeg-commands/28490/

Comment: i donj't get any audio

Comment: @chovy For audio remove the `-an` flag