# How to record the lock screen and other users sessions?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, recording

After I log in to my Linux session I start recording my screen with the command

```
recordmydesktop --fps 2 --no-sound --on-the-fly-encoding --compress-cache --no-frame --v_quality 10
```

But when I to go my lock screen or login into some other user account (while my account is active and has the screen recorder running), the application only records a black screen (on the time I am on the lock screen or in some other user account, when I am on my own account everything is recorded fine. I also tried running the record command as root with `sudo` but it still not recording the lock screen and other users account screen).

How can I record my computer screen, including all computer users and the lock screen?

References:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RecordMyDesktop
2. https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/record-your-screen-from-the-linux-command-line/
3. [FFMpeg : Creating a video clip of approx. 10 seconds when video duration is unknown without audio-](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283878/ffmpeg-creating-a-video-clip-of-approx-10-seconds-when-video-duration-is-unkn)