# merging part of a media file with subtitles for a media file?

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, ffmpeg

I extracted part of a media file using the answer given at [FFMpeg : Creating a video clip of approx. 10 seconds when video duration is unknown without audio-](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283878/ffmpeg-creating-a-video-clip-of-approx-10-seconds-when-video-duration-is-unkn) . In my case it is an .mkv file. The thing is the media file doesn't have subtitles embedded in it. I do have an external subtitle file. Now I want to mux the subtitle file to the video but only of a very small part.

For e.g. let's say the video file is of 1 hour duration. The extracted video is of 2 minutes or 120 seconds. I know the position of the video as well as well as where it is located in the subtitle (srt) file. My question is how to embed/mux the subtitles which are relevant to only that part of the video file and let it remain as it is. I am guessing ffmpeg would be the answer to it, as it is for many things in manipulating media files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same command. `ffmpeg` can also manipulate subtitle. Just replace the video file with subtitle file.

```
ffmpeg -i "A_File_sub.srt" -ss 00:00:0.0 -t 10 "B_File_sub.srt"
```

You'll get a synced subtitle file.
Then merge it using

```
ffmpeg -i B_File.mp4 -i B_File_sub.srt -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text  B_File_With_srt.mp4
```